# Match log files by approximate timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two log files that I'm trying to match up. One table is raw Apache logs from three servers all pulled down to just one userID and the other is that same user's activity in another system. Apache is serving this other system, but the two logs aren't 100% exactly the same timestamp. Apache will have something like 14 entries for every action in the other system. And they usually have the same timestamp, but can also be seconds out of synch. It's only one user, and I am trying to get the IP address of that user from the Apache log to match it up with specific actions on the other log. I can do that if the timestamps are exactly the same.

This works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `a`.`Timestamp`, `a`.`OriginIP`, 
    `a`.`User_browser`, `c`.`Activity_ID`, `c`.`DATA`
    from `Tomcat_server_logs` `a`
    INNER JOIN `user_activity` `c` ON
       `a`.`Timestamp`=`c`.`Timestamp`
       INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT `Timestamp`, `Activity_ID`, `DATA`
          FROM `user_activity`
          GROUP BY `Timestamp`
        ) b ON c.Timestamp = b.Timestamp AND
          c.`Activity_ID` = b.`Activity_ID` AND
          c.`DATA` = b.`DATA`
   WHERE (c.`DATA` LIKE '%submit%') or (c.`DATA` LIKE '%uploadFile')
ORDER BY c.`Timestamp`;
```

But it only gives me IP addresses for this user that are exactly the same timestamp. It skips slightly out-of-synch entries.

I'm afraid I've broken by brain trying to figure out how to say something like this:

```
    ...
    INNER JOIN `user_activity` `c` ON
       ((`a`.`Timestamp` <= ADDTIME(`c`.`Timestamp`,'0 0:0:4') 
       AND (`a`.`Timestamp` >= SUBTIME(`c`.`Timestamp`,'0 0:0:4'))
       INNER JOIN
       ...
```

But obviously that's not a good syntax.

Comment: Why not use BETWEEN?

Comment: `BETWEEN` as Sloan suggested should be fine https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between.

Problem with fuzzy matches though, is that you might get a few logs that _could_ match the same entry. This might be fine if you only have a few records to eyeball - but if it's more (as I expect it will be) - I'd be tempted to write a quick script to trawl through the data and store potential matches to a temporary table somewhere and eyeball them manually. Good luck!

Comment: <= >= or BETWEEN isn't really the problem. The problem is that 

     `INNER JOIN (query) bar ON foo.Timestamp=bar.Timestamp`

works but

    `INNER JOIN (query) bar ON (foo.Timestamp BETWEEN (ADDTIME (bar.Timestamp,'4'), SUBTIME (bar.Timestamp,'4'))`

does not work. It's like it want ON with an = only.